# Does having no trial period on your Google playstore subscription still automatically subscribe the user to the subscription?

Tags: android, google-play, subscription

I am using:

- Flutter
- Revenue Cat

I have tried to find out if you have no trial period for a subscription whether the user is still automatically subscribed. I have setup a manual trial expiring mechanism and I don't want users to be automatically subscribed.

Is this possible? Also, if I do add a trial period to the subscription will the user be notified before they are automatically subscribed? For example:

[image: Trial Ending example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a free trial for your subscription, then after the free trial ends, the user is automatically charged the subscription price (or introductory price if you have set one).

If you do not have a free trial, then the user is charged straight away for the subscription.

If you create a manual mechanism, then the users will not be automatically subscribed as they will have to complete the subscription purchase flow.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I just wanted to find how the user won't be automatically subscribed, because the Google Play stuff is independent of the manual mechanism meaning that even if I put a manual mechanism in place it won't change anything and the user will still be automatically subscribed. Please correct me if I am wrong and also keep in mind that I am using the Revenue cat sdk in Flutter which I am not sure there is support for this.

Comment: No, you can make it not automatic if you first use your own mechanism, and then after the manual mechanism trial ends, use the Google Play subscription mechanism

Comment: Okay I think I understand now. The user has PURCHASE the subscription before these terms apply(Either the 7 day trial or no trial).